# type char to type num mapping

Tags: kdb, q-lang

```
q)type variable
```

returns the type num of the arguement variable.

Is there a mapping that can produce the type char from a type num or do I have to create that dictionary myself?

Ideally something like

```
q)typeChar 1
i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use .Q.t.

```
q).Q.t abs type `test
"s"
q).Q.t abs type 5i
"i"
```

Edit: Or even better just use [.Q.ty](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qty-type)

This seems to return upper case for atoms and lower case for lists.

```
q).Q.ty `test
"S"
q).Q.ty `test`test2
"s"
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use 'key' function :

Reference: http://code.kx.com/q/ref/metadata/#key

Wiki says:  Given a simple list, returns the name of the type as a symbol:

So you can make function like:

```
               q) tyeInChar:{key x,()}
               q) typeInChar  1i // output  `int
               q) typeInChar  "s"  //output `char
```